# What can I do to decrease the impact of TCP's congestion control in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, network-programming, congestion-control

I am carrying out an experiment in which I turn on and off the network for random amounts of time. I expect packet exchange to begin as soon as I turn the network on again. However, I am seeing a sequence of consecutive on and off periods occurring during which no packets are exchanged even in on period.

I suspect this is because of exponential backoffs implemented as part of congestion control in TCP. Probably the duration of off and on periods fall such that the next timeout lies during an off period and becuase of exponential nature, it doubles next time. This is affecting my experimental results. What linux kernel parameters can I change so that I get rid of the effects of exponential backoff and rather see packet exchange as soon as the network is up again?

Comment: If your experiment requires some transport with different characteristics from TCP's, use another transport. If your experiment includes TCP as a precondition, what you're asking for is a way to falsify your results.

Comment: I understand your point of view and what you are trying to say. I can always claim that I am proposing solutions and performing experiments for simplified versions which can be improved upon for true TCP at later stages. As you suggest, yes, I should ideally be using a protocol other than TCP with the characteristics I want. The problem is I am using libraries that build upon TCP. I can't afford to not use those libraries, thus am trying to change the characteristics of TCP in linux, if possible.

Comment: I would also be glad if you could suggest protocols that behave like TCP in every way apart from having exponential backoff congestion control. I am currently trying to bring in a linear congestion control algorithm for TCP.

Comment: In short, the exp doesn't have TCP as a precondition but is relying on it because the WebSocket library I am using uses it. I need a WebSockets implementation that is reliable but doesn't have congestion control.

Answer (score 0):

To decrease the impact, you need to optimize some [kernel variables](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) : lower *rto_min* and increase *tcp_retries2*.

> I am currently trying to bring in a linear congestion control
>   algorithm for TCP.

Did you achieve this goal ?